# ConversionFailedException for request with enum

Tags: java, spring, enums

In my spring-boot application, I have an endpoint with a "ReadOrderRequest"
In the request model, I have an enum field SourceSystem:

```
@ApiParam(value = "Source crm system for the order")
private SourceSystem sourceSystem;
```

This is how my SourceSystem Enum looks like:

```
package qwerty.resources.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;

public enum SourceSystem {
    ABC("abc"),
    DEF("def"),
    GHI("ghi");

    private final String value;

    SourceSystem(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    @JsonCreator
    public static SourceSystem fromValue(String value) {
        for (SourceSystem system : SourceSystem.values()) {
            if (system.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                return system;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    @JsonValue
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

The swagger is generated like this:

```
          {
            "name": "sourceSystem",
            "in": "query",
            "description": "Source crm system for the order",
            "required": false,
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "abc",
              "def",
              "ghi"
            ]
          },
```

However when using the endpoint, I get the exception below.

```
"readOrdersRequest: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'qwerty.resources.model.SourceSystem' for property 'sourceSystem'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@io.swagger.annotations.ApiParam qwerty.resources.model.SourceSystem] for value 'abc'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant qwerty.resources.model.SourceSystem.abc"
```

So it seems like the issue is that the value (lowercase) is sent in to the endpoint, which then find no match since the actual enum is uppercase. However I think that the "fromValue" method should solve this issue, but unfortunately this is not the case.

Do you have any suggestions on how I can solve this issue?

First time post, let me know if i need to modify it :)

Comment: It's a _really bad idea_ to override `toString` on an enum. Add a `getValue()` method, put `@JsonValue` on that, and drop your `@JsonCreator` (read the docs; it's unnecessary for an enum).

Comment: @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic-

Thanks! I read the docs understood why JsonValue was sufficient enough and removing JsonCreator solved my problem! :)

Why is overriding toString() method a bad idea for enums? Tried to find but in general it seems to be used quite often with JsonValue:
"A typical usage is that of annotating toString() method so that returned String value is used as the JSON serialization"


This article mentions that for enums:
"In fact, overwriting the toString() method is encouraged."
https://dzone.com/articles/enum-using-the-name-and-tostring-methods-correctly

Comment: On enums _specifically_, when the enum is printed for debugging or logging (as part of some other object's `toString()`, usually), most developers expect that the value printed is the same as the name. Remember that `toString()` is not intended for end users; the audience is _other developers_, and the [Rule of Least Surprise](http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/ch11s01.html) indicates leaving it as the useful default for enums.